# Using animateWithDuration when a button is pressed but it has no effect (swift 2)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using the following code to have a label slide onto the screen when a button is pressed, but it's having no effect.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    summaryLabel.alpha = 0

}

@IBAction func searchButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2) { () -> Void in

        self.summaryLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.summaryLabel.center.x - 400, self.summaryLabel.center.y)
        self.summaryLabel.alpha = 1
        self.summaryLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.summaryLabel.center.x + 400, self.summaryLabel.center.y)

    }

    //button code continues...
```

I've tested what's going on by fixing the alpha at 1, but the label just stays where it is and does not move when the button is pressed. What am I missing?

Comment: why do you have two lines of code changing self.summaryLabel.center

Comment: I was trying to move the label (that has alpha = 0) off the screen when the button is pressed, and then bring it into view with a 2 second animation

Comment: move the first line outside the animation block. Or create two different animations, but be careful the second one should occur only after the first one finished

Comment: just tried your suggestion, but the label stays stationary when the button is pressed. it behaves the same as if there was no animateWithDuration at all

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

First of all, your two changes to the view's center cancel each other out. The animation applies the full set of changes that are inside the animation block all in one animation. If the end result is no change, then no change is applied. As Ramy says in his comment, you either need 2 animations, timed so the second one takes place after the first one has completed, or you nee to apply the first change before the animation begins. I would suggest starting with a single change, and a single animation, and get that working first.

Second problem: View controllers use auto layout by default. With auto layout, you can't animate the position of a view directly. It doesn't work reliably. Instead, you have to put a constraint on the view, connect it to an outlet, and the animate a change to the constraint's constant value by changing the constant and calling `layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation block. The call to `layoutIfNeeded()` inside the animation block causes the view's position to be changed, and since it's inside the animation block, the change is applied with animation.